# Check public address balance

Tags: address, api

I am willing to write Python script to check for some public addresses balances. I understand that I need to access API of known exchanges (Coinbase, Binance). I also know that there will be limit of requests sent in time.

As far as I can see there is possibility to check for wallet balances. But what about checking some public BTC addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

addr=input('Enter address to check: ')

if addr=='':
    exit()

r=requests.get('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/'+addr)

if not r.status_code==200:
    print('Error',r.status_code)
    exit()

b=int(r.text)

print(addr,'\t',r.text,'sat\t',b/100000,'mBTC\t',b/100000000,'BTC')
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* access an API and be limited by their ToS but you don't have to.

All transactions (`TX`) and BTC addresses (`pubKey`) are public on the blockchain with the distinction that all TX are recorded, but `pubKeys` show up only once mentioned in a `TX`.

Assuming you're talking about bitcoin and not something else you should run `bitcoind` on your machine and query it locally without limitations.

`bitcoin-cli getbalance`

Comment: `getbalance` is about wallet, not transactions in the blockchain...

Answer (score 1):

You can use services like [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/), [blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/) or [tokenview.io](https://tokenview.io/) to explore crypto addresses. It will show you balance, a list of transactions, date and time and some additional info.
As for your script, you can use `requests` library to send requests to API and receive JSON data or scrape the web-sites directly using `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.